# How can I shift timezone of Date object created in local timezone to target timezone in GWT client?

Tags: gwt, date, timezone, google-cloud-datastore, gwt2

How can I shift timezone of Date object created in local timezone to target timezone?

Here is what I need. I want web-client to pick a date using [DatePicker](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.html) but resulting Date object should look like **as if it was picked in another timezone**. Since there is no way to tell `DatePicker` to do that I have to manually shift date.

For example it's Apr 6th 2012 2:42AM in California right now. Created Date will be in UTC-7 timezone. I want to have Date object with Apr 6th 2012 2:42AM in Europe/Moscow timezone.

Here is I do it right now:

```
final TimeZoneConstants constTz = GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class);
final TimeZone timeZoneMsk = TimeZone.createTimeZone(constTz.europeMoscow());
final TimeZone timeZoneCali = TimeZone.createTimeZone(constTz.americaLosAngeles());

Date curTime = new Date();

DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFullDateTimeFormat();
Date mskTime = new Date(curTime.getTime() - (curTime.getTimezoneOffset() - timeZoneMsk.getStandardOffset()) * 60 * 1000);

String strLocal = dateTimeFormat.format(curTime, timeZoneCali); // Friday, 2012 April 06 02:42:59 Pacific Daylight Time
String strMsk = dateTimeFormat.format(mskTime, timeZoneMsk);    // Friday, 2012 April 06 02:42:59 Moscow Standard Time
```

There are two problems with this method:

- If you ask me it looks pretty bizarre.
- Timezone in `mskTime` is still -0007. I wonder if it can cause any problems in future when I deserialize this object from Google App Engine datastore.

Or should I just produce string with full date of local Californian time, replace timezone in string and then generate new `Date` by calling `DateTimeFormat.parse()` ? It looks pretty hacky too...

Also what do you think of [JodaTime for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-joda-time/) ? Is it stable enough for production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks about right. Using `DateTimeFormat.parse` might make the intention clearer to a casual reader. It's not very often that you are given timezones A and B and one `Date` object, and you have to produce a new `Date` object that, when formatted in B, has the same time as the original when formatted in A.

> Timezone in mskTime is still -0007. I wonder if it can cause any problems in future when I deserialize this object from Google App Engine datastore.

No, there can be no problems. Remember that a `Date` object represents a universal point in time  not bound to a timezone. When it's April 6 14:40 in Moscow, it's April 6 03:40 in California, so the `Date` objects are equal.